# Sphinx error: unknown local index "INDEX_NAME" in search request

Tags: php, sphinx

Im using Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117) and sphinxapi.php (http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/tags/REL_0_9_9_RC2/api/sphinxapi.php).

When I testing searching in command shell: "search -i INDEX_NAME test" everything is
perfect, but when I connect to Sphinx by sphinxapi.php this error occur.

sphinx.conf is configured properly, index created...

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: fixed: Sphinx need to be restarted after first creating index

Comment: Looking for how to restart sphinx... will post back once I have found out how..

Comment: To restart sphinx:


/usr/local/bin/searchd --stop 
and then:
/usr/local/bin/searchd -c /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf