# Thinking Sphinx after deployment - ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (unknown local index 'user_core' in search request):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I check this topic: [Sphinx error: unknown local index "INDEX_NAME" in search request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329846/sphinx-error-unknown-local-index-index-name-in-search-request) , but it's closed and it's not resolve problem in my rails application.

I update TS to 3.0.2, and include it to deploy.rb. I also change code in model. Now it works in development, and some examples work in test, and some not. But after successful deployment I get error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (unknown local index 'user_core' in search request):
```

I try rebuild, restart, and other things, but it doesn't work :(

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: by TC do you mean TS (Thinking Sphinx)? And there's no 3.0.4 release of that yet...

Comment: Also: what's the output when you run rebuild?

Comment: I am so sorry, it is of course Thinking Sphinx in version 3.0.2
In production (RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:rebuild) it return (last two line):

Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/michal/coach-app/releases/20130602185224/log/production.searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd. Check the log files for more information.

Comment: What version of Sphinx do you have installed in production?

Comment: Sphinx 2.0.5-id64-release (r3308)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's already a Sphinx daemon running that Thinking Sphinx hasn't stopped (if you're still getting the same error) so I'd recommend killing that rogue searchd process (which you should be able to find via `ps aux | grep searchd` - and, if the permissions are fine, `killall searchd` will stop that Sphinx process).

Comment: How is it not working? Is there a process there and you can't kill it? Is there no process? What's the output when you run the following: `searchd --pidfile --config /home/michal/coach-app/current/config/production.sphinx.conf`

Comment: No, I killed and still don't work.

Sphinx 2.0.5-id64-release (r3308)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/home/michal/coach-app/current/config/production.sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: compat_sphinxql_magics=1 is deprecated; please update your application and config
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...

Comment: It's indicating that Sphinx (or something else) is running on port 9306 already - are you sure you killed the process?

Comment: I killed by "killall searchd", but it creates new process with searchd.

Comment: Automatically? Or when you run rebuild? Rebuild is supposed to start it again. If you're seeing that 'bind failed' error and rebuild is the process starting the first daemon, then perhaps you're manually requiring the thinking_sphinx tasks in your Rakefile? That's not necessary with Rails 3.

Comment: One more time. I did deploy (instruction in TS page), next I get error, so I go by ssh to server and try to rebuild manualy (I don't think it's good idea). It doesn't work so I tried kill searchid and it also doesn't work. I've got Rails 3.2.11 and thinking sphinx 3.0.2.

Comment: Maybe this answer didn't help the OP but it helped me track down an issue in my local environment. I had started `sphinx` from a different application, so running `rake ts:start` failed. Killing the rouge `searchd` process solved my problem.